# Dharmaskandha and Śāripūtrābhidharma Satipatthana contains a section of shortcomings. What are the shortcomings?

Tags: vipassana, history, satipatthana

According to [Satipatthana Mula (By Sujato Bhikkhu edited by Piya Tan)](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/13.4-Satipatthana-Mula-m10-sujato.pdf) Dharmaskandha and Śāripūtrābhidharma versions of the Satipatthana contains a section of shortcomings. What are the shortcomings mentioned in these versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it in another way Sujato Bhikkhu postulates a root text which he calls Satipatthana Mula which other later Satipatthana suttas and sutras "added" their own stuff. He derived a postulated root text not just by elision and finding common contents but other textual analysis.

The results he obtained happened to be similar to those found in the Theravada Abidhamma Vibhanga.

My quick and brief comparison from his table shows that the current pali version contains the following practices which according to Sujato Bhikkhu are not present in his postulated Satipatthana Mula:

**Theravada Satipatthna Sutta adds:**

Four postures;
Clear comprehension;
Anapanasati;

4 elements;
Food;
Space (5 element);
Oozing orifices;
Charnel ground;

6 sense media;
4 noble truths;
Rise/fall;
Knowledge;
Independence

**Ekayana Sutra added:** Arahantship